# How to one hot encode the response variable in tfdatasets r?

Tags: r, tensorflow-datasets

I'am trying use tfdatasets package in R in order to produce a pipeline that takes an tibble/dataframe and outputs a one hot encoded response variable of Species. How do I transform the response variable (y) with tfdatasets in order to output Species as one hot encoded?

Desired output is:

versicolor, setosa, virginica

0, 1, 0
...

Comment: Hi, @Allan A, did you find out the answer for this question? I am starting to explore `tfds` and `tfdatasets` packages, and I am till confused about...  It would be useful to other users if you share any answer you find for it... we observe documentation for python versions... but not for r...

Comment: Hi @hamagust, Thanks for your question, I have found a sufficient workaround atleast, i will share it below. I hope it helps someone. Best regards Allan

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comment above, this is a workaround that works for my purposes, but is not necessarily a 100% pure tfdatasets solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rsample)
library(recipes)
library(reticulate)
library(tensorflow)
library(tfdatasets)
library(keras)

iris %>%
  recipe(Species ~ .) %>%
  step_dummy(Species,
             one_hot = T) %>%
  prep() %>%
  juice() %>%
  select(contains("Species")) %>%
  as.matrix() %>%
  tensor_slices_dataset()
```

The solution has less pure tfdatasets pipeline, whilst the workaround below is a more pure approach.

```
iris %>%
  mutate(Species = Species %>%
           as.integer()) %>%
  select(Species) %>%
  tensor_slices_dataset() %>%
  dataset_map(function(iteration){
   
    iteration$Species <- tf$one_hot(iteration$Species,
                                    3L)
    iteration
   
  })
```